# AngularJS - Assinging variables inside http call from function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm desperate for help.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
$scope.getData = function(id)
{
    $http.get('/url' + id).success(function (data) {
        return data.a.b.c;
    });
};
```

now in my other function I have something like this:

```
$scope.obj= {};
        $scope.obj.name = $scope.user.displayName;
        $scope.commentObj.id= $scope.id;
        $scope.obj.blah = blah;
       $scope.obj.otherDataThing = $scope.getUserProfileData($scope.commentObj.userId);
```

now this variable is NEVER getting set when I post to the url to create the actual data object in mongo. It just doesn't show up. I know it has to do w the syncronicity of it, but I can't figure it out. Help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just set `myObj = data` or `myObj.prop = data` or `myObj.prop.push(data)` or whatever it is that you want to do inside your `$http` call.

```
function ... = (passed) {
    $http.get('url' + passed).success(function (data) {
        $scope.myObj = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I have an extra dot, like $scope.myObj.something and when I try this or anything .something doesn't get set :( any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use convention

Make promised function

```
function MyCoolFunction(passed) {
     return $http.get('url' + passed)); //<-- return $http
     //_____________________^__________ this should be comma (,)
}
```

Then call it

```
$scope.obj= {};
$scope.obj.name = $scope.user.displayName;
$scope.commentObj.id= $scope.id;
//_________________^_____ assigning to id property but using $scope.commentObj.userId
$scope.obj.blah = blah;

MyCoolFunction($scope.commentObj.userId).then(function(successResponse){ // <-- success_callback    
        $scope.obj.otherDataThing = successResponse.a.b.c; // <-- assignment of result
    }, function(errorResponse){ // <-- error callback
        $scope.error = errorResponse.message || errorResponse;
});
```

Comment: this doesnt work when I use dot notation like myObj.someproperty

Comment: It works! Check you object, put console.log everywhere, that example i showed is totally legit.

Comment: @Tom if still didn't fixed, make plunker/jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it.
we are using defer

in my service :: productService.js

```
angular.module('appName')
    .service('ProductService', function ($http, $q, $window) {
        var base_url = $window.base_url;

    this.get_products = function (data) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var where = data || {};
                $http
                    .get(base_url + '/item', { params: where })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }, function (err) {
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            };

});
```

then in the controllers you can inject the sevice and get it via

```
$scope.products = [];
    ProductService
       .get_products({ page: self.page })
                .then(function (resp) {
                   $scope.products = resp.a.b;
                   console.log(resp);
                   // success response
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    // Error Response
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just solving it by nesting the http calls. Something like this:

```
http.get = function ...
    http.post = function...
```

can't believe I didn't think of that before *facepalm*